# "Game Over" not disappearing after clicking for second time on "Start game" in Whack-a-mole

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I just started learning jQuery and have made a Whack-a-mole game. The game is working just fine. But once the game gets over and I click the start game button again, the game starts but "Game Over" message is still there.

Here is the link to my repo: https://github.com/kshitiz20/Whack-a-mole

Here is the link to the game:  https://kshitiz20.github.io/Whack-a-mole/

How do i fix this bug?

Comment: Please include the relevant details in your question.

Comment: I am learning right now. What details should i include? And what did you find irrelevant?

Comment: Nothing in your question was irrelevant, but we shouldn't have to travel off-site to find your code (and figure out what part isn't working). See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Okay. I will keep that in mind. Thank you for your feedback. :)

Comment: Just an FYI that's why I downvoted. I see (currently) you have one upvote on your post, presumably from the answerer. Definitely keep that in mind, as your lucky this one wasn't closed!

Comment: Yeah.  As I mentioned already, I am a beginner right now. Will get to know about the aesthetics, if developers like you will maintain providing support to us new developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this shouild work for you:

```
function startGame(){
    makeGameBoard();
    score=0;
    $('.score').text(score);
    startMoles();
    gameOver=false;
    $('.message').html(''); <-- clear the html
    setTimeout(function(){
        return gameend();
    },15000);
}
```